# Nativescript - http.request post json

Tags: nativescript

Sorry for the title, but i didn´t know how to explain it better. The thing is, i´m not getting any response from server-side and this is my code:

**my .js file:**

```
http.request({
                url: "http://myPhpFile",
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                content: JSON.stringify({ deviceToken: token, ambiente: platformModule.device.os })
            }).then(function (response) {

                console.log(response);
            }, function (e) {
                // console.log("Error occurred " + e);
            })
```

**my .php file:**

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $data["deviceToken"];

?>
```

My console.log in my .js file doesn´t show anything in the terminal, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks, regards

Comment: What do you see in the console if you uncomment `console.log("Error occurred " + e);`?

Comment: Hi there...thanks for answering, i see nothing...

Comment: It turns out, it was a problem with my wi-fi